# Como Invocar un Metodo C# desde una funcion JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, aplicación-web

Necesito llamar un método `C#` desde una función `JavaScript...`, en el momento que el usuario intenta abandonar la pagina... en tal caso que se pueda mi función es la siguiente:

```
window.addEventListener('unload', function(event) {
   // Invocar Metodo C# AQUI
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Podrías invocar un `WebMethod` para invocar funcionalidad de forma asíncrona al servidor

[Calling ASP.Net WebMethod using jQuery AJAX](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Calling-ASPNet-WebMethod-using-jQuery-AJAX.aspx)

Como veras en el articulo usa el `$.ajax`:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "CS.aspx/GetCurrentTime",
    data: '{name: "' + $("#<%=txtUserName.ClientID%>")[0].value + '" }',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: OnSuccess,
    failure: function(response) {
        alert(response.d);
    }
});
```

Definiendo en el código de la pagina:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string GetCurrentTime(string name)
{
    return "Hello " + name + Environment.NewLine + "The Current Time is: "
        + DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

De esta forma en el evento `JavaScript` que detecta el cambio de `page` puede invocar código en el servidor

Comment: No hace nada , .. y no nesecito pasar parametro ...esta linea me da error '{name: "' + $("#<%=txtUserName.ClientID%>")[0].value + '" }',

Comment: ok, si lo puse es un ejemplo, sino necesits parametro se lo puede quitar. Como es que no hace nada? no tendras algun error de javasctipt? puede validarlo con el developer tools del browser,  agregaste la libreria jquery ?

Comment: jajja si falta ba la linea de la referencia Jquery

Answer (score 4):

Esto se puede hacer sin necesidad de JavaScript. Si tienes `AutoEventWireup` con valor `true` (tiene valor `true` por defecto, como se indica en la [documentación de MSDN](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/kb/814745)), puedes enlazar los eventos a los métodos de controlador de eventos poniendo "Page_" y el nombre del evento.

Así, en el caso particular del evento `unload`, puedes definir el controlador directamente en C# de este modo, y se llamará cuando el evento `unload` de la página sea lanzado:

```
protected void Page_Unload(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // tu código
}
```

Comment: Gracias Alvaro Montoro...muy bueno pruebo y te comento....